# Which is the correct interrogative form?

Tags: grammar

Which of the two is correct?

1. Who should an English teacher be? 2. Who should be an English teacher?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In case 1., it is asking for the qualifications of the job, while in case 2., it is asking who out of a group of people should be one.
They are both correct.